# Aframe move vr-camera-component

Tags: mobile, camera, touch, aframe

I move my camera when i trigger an event and it works perfectly on pc but not when im on my phone in the vr-mode. Need to fix this here some code:

```
<a-entity id="camentity" rotation="0 90 0">
  <a-camera id="cam" user-height="0" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls>
    <a-animation attribute="position" begin="movecam_1" duration="500" from="0 0 0" to="-40 0 -50"></a-animation>
    <a-animation attribute="position" begin="movecam_1_bc" duration="500" from="-40 0 -50" to="0 0 0"></a-animation>
 </a-camera>  
</a-entity>  

function kameramove_1() {
    document.querySelector( "#cam" ).emit('movecam_1');
    }

function kameramove_1_back() {
    document.querySelector( "#cam" ).emit('movecam_1_bc');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate the camera rig (parent of the camera, camentity in your case) not the camera itself:

```
    <a-entity id="camentity" rotation="0 90 0">
      <a-animation attribute="position" begin="movecam_1" duration="500" from="0 0 0" to="-40 0 -50"></a-animation>
      <a-animation attribute="position" begin="movecam_1_bc" duration="500" from="-40 0 -50" to="0 0 0"></a-animation>
      <a-camera id="cam"></a-camera>  
    </a-entity>
```