# Virtual reality world camera html

Tags: aframe

I made a virtual reality world and used the tag  to move the Camera around (the person viewing it). And when I use my phone to view my world, it works until I put it on the mode meant for Google Cardboard (VR headset)

Comment: Needs additional info. Link to reproduce, used phone and browser... What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Go to coral-fowl.glitch.me

Comment: You’ll see that normally the camera will move u up and around. As soon as I hit the vr button and u r in be more, you don’t move.

Comment: Animate a camera rig, not the camera itself. [More info in similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134295/aframe-move-vr-camera-component)

Comment: i tried it, does nothing.

Comment: glitch.com/edit/#!/coral-fowl This is my coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate a camera rig, not the camera itself. More info in similar question

The [begin attribute](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/animations.html#begin) defines when the animation starts playing: a delay or an event. I don’t see any events fired in your code that trigger the animations.

Remove the `begin` attributes to see the animation playing: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/caring-otter

Also use A-Frame 0.8.2 instead of 0.8.0

Also notice you have two position animations under camera. One will override the other.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct and open a separate question for sound. For the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091783/how-do-you-create-links-in-a-frame